# How to remote connect from Windows 10 to Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 using default desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, ubuntu-18.04, windows-10-desktop

I need to remote connect to Ubuntu Budgie desktop, from Windows 10 Pc.

I've tryed and have been connected through tightvncserver and tight vnc viewer but not for long. Later after connection ended, made my Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) unresponsive to mouse/keyb.
I have installed Budgie, but cannot connect as I get a greyish screen or no screen at all.
I've also tryed xrdp, same results, following every available tutorial on net:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031519/xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04lts)
- https://www.lifewire.com/setup-ubuntu-remote-desktop-4129666
- https://websiteforstudents.com/connect-to-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-desktop-via-remote-desktop-connection-rdp-with-xrdp/

I want to use the opensourse and native in Ubuntu programs, not third party.
With Remmina connection to Win10 is flawless, why is it the opposite so hard to achieve?
I need to connect to Budgie desktop, not an lxde vs xfce alternative.
Can anyone help with a step by step approach?

Answer (score -1):

Finally, after waiting for a good samaritan to post an answer, I've found a way to achieve remote connection to Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 desktop server from a Windows 10 client, through the use of x11vnc.

I've run the following to install x11vnc in Ubuntu Budgie terminal::

```
sudo apt-get install x11vnc
```

Since I've been connected on a local lan, haven't set up an SSH tunner for extra security, but only set up a user password.

```
x11vnc -storepasswd
```

Next I've typed "x11vnc" at Terminal and got it up running.

```
x11vnc
```

From the client Windows 10 machine, I run the following in cmd:

```
mstsc.exe
```

The remote desktop connect application of Windows 10, asked the remote ip for connection, which I got it beforehand from the linux machine.

After entering user id and password, i got remote connected to Ubuntu Budgie desktop. For half an hour everything went o.k., but later connection lost with following message:

> *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

Searching around internet for a fix to retain an established connection, I got pages saying about reported bugs in x11vnc, a workaround to source code recompile, etc.

With trial and error, only the followng workaround posted [here](https://thespecter.net/blog/technology/opensourcediy/x11vnc-stack-mashing-detected/) , fixed the connection between Ubuntu and Windows 10 machines, using x11vnc.

```
x11vnc -noxrecord
```

So for now, I can connect to an Ubuntu (Budgie) machine from Windows 10, on local lan, without issues.